# Getting error while uploading files to Amazon AWS Cloud from Visual Studio

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to AWS Cloud from Visual Studio 2015. But I am getting the error *A WebException with status NameResolutionFailure was thrown.*

I have tried using all regions through intellisense but it is of no use.

Below is my Code. Can anyone help on this.

```
public void sendMyFileToS3(System.IO.Stream localFilePath, string bucketName, string subDirectoryInBucket, string fileNameInS3)
{
    IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);            
    TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);
    TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
     if (subDirectoryInBucket == "" || subDirectoryInBucket == null)
            {
                request.BucketName = bucketName;
            }
            else
            {    
                request.BucketName = bucketName + @"/" + subDirectoryInBucket;
            }
            request.Key = fileNameInS3; //file name up in S3  
            request.InputStream = localFilePath;
            try
            {
                utility.Upload(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
}
```

Comment: Hello, have you enable encryption on the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

The Only thing I can think of in the code above is that your code is not located under USWest2, can you confirm ?

Comment: Yes....But I have tried for all other location as well....eg EUWest3 etc....Is there I can check via code in which region the bucket is created?
As when I tried to create a new bucket with the same name I am getting error that bucket already created.